# What timezone does DST refer to?

Tags: ubuntu, timezone, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL with ubuntu 16.04, and was having network issues today. Here's what date outputs

```
$ date
Thu Sep 21 13:37:00 DST 2017
```

What does DST refer to? I know it stands for "Daylight savings time", but that's [not a timezone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations). I'm suspicious that it's a contrived timezone that changes on the equinox, which would explain my problem today.

I was able to fix my problem by setting my timezone to `US/Pacific`, which changed the output to `PDT`:

```
$ date
Thu Sep 21 13:37:00 PDT 2017
```

However, I have a second machine with the same problem, and am curious what timezone it thinks its in.

Is there anyway to get the `X/Y` string (Olson database name) that corresponds to `DST` out of the system?

Comment: I have software that can search the IANA/Olson database for abbreviations used during a local time (https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#convert_by_timezone_abbreviation).  I've run this software on your timestamp, and it comes up empty.  There are no IANA time zones using DST as their abbreviation with this local time stamp.  As a sanity check, I reran the search with PDT and came up with 6 candidates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** WSL Dynamically generates a fake timezone info file at `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Msft/localtime` that in hard linked to `/etc/localtime`. The Msft file uses the made up names `DST` or `STD`, and they stand for no specific timezone.

---

What is actually going on is WSL attempts to match your Windows timezone in Linux. This is a non-trivial mapping, as seen [here](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/zone_tzid.html) ([discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967903/linux-windows-timezone-mapping)). So rather than trying to hit a constantly moving target, what I believe WSL does is use the [Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725481(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the Windows Timezone info, and based off of that information, it dynamically generates a [timezone info file](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tzfile.5.html).

I believe that `wslhost` (specifically code in `C:\Windows\System32\lxss\LxssManager.dll`) does this inspection on your current timezone in Windows, and writes to the the `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Msft/localtime` file. This is why when the timezone in Windows changes, you see the affect in an already running WSL instantly. But since there is no perfect mapping from Windows timezones to Linux or POSIX timezones, `wslhost` probably just *wings* the name, and that's where the DST comes into play.

*Update:* Actually, I think it just says "DST" if you are in Daylight Saving Zone timezone, and "STD" for non DST timezone (Standard I assume).

So the answer to "What timezone does DST stand for" is none, and any Linux program that will attempt to match `/etc/localtime` to a timezone file in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` (via readlink or just searching), will only every get "Msft/localtime" as an answer. A "Technically accurate, but totally useless" answer.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: This answer is likely wrong; the output reported by the OP is inconsistent with my hypothesis.

I believe it's an unrecognized time zone, interpreted as UTC by the `date` command.

On my Ubuntu 14.04 system:

```
$ date -u ; TZ=DST date ; TZ=NOSUCHTIMEZONE date
Thu Sep 21 21:04:44 UTC 2017
Thu Sep 21 21:04:44 DST 2017
Thu Sep 21 21:04:44 NOSUCHTIMEZONE 2017
$
```

Probably something set your `$TZ` environment variable to `DST`.

Check your environment (`echo $TZ`).  If it doesn't print `DST`, I'm wrong. (EDIT: The OP says `$TZ` is empty.)

(There's nothing called `DST` under `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.)

Comment: But the fact that you show the same time, `13:37:00`, for `DST` and `PDT` suggests otherwise. Is that literally the output you got?

Comment: Yep, after running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`, that's what i got. `date +%z` on the broken machine gives `-0700`. Perhaps I'm jumping to conclusions, but it seems suspicious that I started having problems with DST on the equinox. I don't know what output `date` had yesterday

Comment: `$TZ` is empty.

Comment: @Eric: What's in `/etc/timezone`?

Comment: That file doesn't exist on the broken system - seems that WSL does not create it by default

Comment: Grasping at straws here. Could there be something else in your environment? Try `env | egrep -i 'zone|tz|dst'`. Or `env | less` and look for anything strange. Does `TZ=DST date` give you different output from `date`? Try a date that's not during daylight saving time: `date -d 2018-01-01`

Comment: On my system, `/etc/localtime` is a symlink to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles`. What is it on yours? It's a mostly binary file with a line of plain text at the end; what does `tail -n 1 /etc/localtime` show? Also, does `date +%Z` print `DST`?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, the DST in this case actually does refer to daylight savings time.

Ubuntu has been notorious for bugs regarding the DST adjustment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/595569/update-time-for-daylight-savings-time-set-system-clock-to-utc-time-and-stay-in

Comment: Right, but DST in which timezone?

Comment: Maybe not; see my answer.